# Simple Question: Stopped Martingale Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales

A drunk man is at the 17th meter of a 100-meter-long bridge. He has 0.5 probability of moving forward or backward one meter each step.

What is the expected number of steps he takes to reach either the beginning or the end of the bridge?

---

Solution:

The martingale stops at $n$ is also a martingale. Let $N =$ stop time.

$E[S^2_N - N] = E[p_a *83^2 + (1-p_a )* 17^2]-E[N] = S_0^2-0 = 0. \rightarrow E[N] = 1441$.

**Confusion: I understand $E[Martingale] = E[M_0]$, but how come $E[S_N^2 - N] =0?$**

Comment: Should be $1411$ and not $1441$, I believe

Comment: @MarcusStuhr, I believe is 17*83

Comment: Yes -- but the current post (as it stands) is using $1441$ (probably a typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your main confusion seems to be over $E(S_n^2-n) = 0$ for any $n$, I will give an explanation for you. We start by rewriting $S_n^2$, namely

$$S_n^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 + \sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j,$$ thus we can rewrite the expectation by

\begin{align}E(S_n^2-n) &= E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right) + E\left(\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j\right) - E(n)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nE\left(X_i^2\right) + \sum_{i\neq j}E\left(X_iX_j\right) - n.\end{align}

Now, we note by independence of the steps that $X_i \perp X_j, i \neq j$, hence $E(X_iX_j) = E(X_i)E(X_j) = 0$. And, because $X_i \in \{-1,1\}$, we have that $X_i^2 = 1$, thus we get that

\begin{align}E(S_n^2-n) &= \sum_{i=1}^nE\left(X_i^2\right) + \sum_{i\neq j}E\left(X_iX_j\right) - n\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n1 + \sum_{i\neq j}0 - n = n-n = 0.
\end{align}

**EDIT:**

Now, consider a random $N$ with $P(N=n) = p_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. There are two easy ways of seeing that this result extends from $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to $N$.

Method 1:

We have that $E(S_N^2-N | N = n) = E(S^2_n - n) = 0$ by above. Therefore, $$E(S_N^2 - N) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty E(S_N^2-N | N = n) p_n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty0\cdot p_n = 0.$$

Method 2:

By the same expansion as before, we have that 
$$E(S_N^2-N) = \sum_{i=1}^NE\left(X_i^2\right) + \sum_{i\neq j}E\left(X_iX_j\right) - E(N),$$ but by [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) we have that this first sum is simply $E(N)E(X_1^2) =  E(N)\cdot 1 = E(N)$, hence the result follows immediately.

Comment: I understand now. However, I have one more concern, how come $E[n]=n$?

Comment: The expectation of a constant is a constant. Now to extend this to random  $N$ we use Wald's theorem to state that the first random sum is equal to $E(N)E(X_1^2) = E(N)$ hence we get $E(S_N^2 - N) = E(N) - E(N) = 0$

Comment: @wrek I've added an explanation for extending it from real $n$ to random $N$. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks!

Comment: @David It's been a few years, but quick question: In method 2, why do we need Wald's equality to show the first sum is $E[N]$, or were you just introducing it as an alternative option? Couldn't we apply the same logic in your first proof, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n 1$. The only difference is the summation occurs a random $N$ times instead of a fixed $n$ times.

Comment: Another question is, how would you solve for $\sum_{i \neq j} E[X_i]X[X_j]$ if $E[X_i], E[X_j] \neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The process $M_n = S_n^2 - n$ is also a martingale (exercise).  By optional stopping, $M_{n \wedge N}$ is also a martingale, so $0=E[M_{n \wedge N}] = E[S_{n \wedge N}^2] - E[n \wedge N]$ for all $n$.

Now note that as $n \to \infty$, we have $E[S_{n \wedge N}^2] \to E[S_N^2]$ by dominated convergence (it is dominated by $100^2$) and $E[n \wedge N] \to E[N]$ by monotone convergence.

Comment: What is that $M_{n \wedge N}$?

Comment: @wrek: $a \wedge b$ is the minimum of $a,b$.

Comment: Is it possible for your to elaborate the first two sentence. I still don't understand how come $E[S^2_n - n]=0$